# push notification is not working on iphone4

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have used push notification in my app it works well on iphone3 :)
but when I am using iphone4 my app is not able to get device token .
and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

is not called 
how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push notification wont work in jailbroken device.

Comment: if iam using other apps like viber then push is working on it ??

Comment: code is simple problem is that my app on iphone4 is not getting token

Comment: @GhostRider r u asking for help or u want to solve it? If u r asking about how to implement then i will help you

Comment: I am asking for help. i have to implement push notification

Comment: Did this used to be true?  I have a jailbroken iOS 5 iPhone 4, and all my push notifications work fine.  Did you mean to say that push notifications won't work for jailbreak **apps**?  In other words, apps not signed with Apple certificates (APNS-enabled provisioning profiles)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a jailbroken device and the push notification works fine, so to be exact the push notification service doesn't work on what is called hacktivated devices which are jailbroken devices with no factory unlock.